# How can i keep log of every bots (google, yahoo etc) visit to my website

Tags: php, seo

How can I keep record/log of every bot's visit to my website. I want to know how frequently crawlers are crawling my website and which pages are being indexed or crawled. Is there any php script which i can use to know the visits of google, yahoo and other bots.

Comment: Do you have access to your server logs? Analyzing them with one of many different log analyzers would be your best option.

Comment: can I do that using some php script automatically. I am looking some easy and time saving solution. logs Analysing is little bit manual method :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

parse your log files for the user agent
i have seperate log files in the first place
google the rest for yourself or consider accepting some answers

Answer (score 0):

use awstats or robotstats,
it will do the job.